# grab a value from a database, and use a forloop to fill a drop down menu in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I've created a rather large dynamic site as a project, and everything is working, except one function.

I'm using PHP to display an HTML table that populates from my database. I can grab the value of `ip_stock`, which is an int value, I want to take that value, and forloop through it, to populate a drop down menu for each item to be purchased in the table. Each item will have a different value in `['ip_stock']`. Here is my code, minus some of the HTML at the top, which is not very relative, but the connection is made and successful, my forloop doesn't work, and doesn't work if I put it in the selection code itself.

```
   <?php 

    $pagerows = 5;

    if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) {
        $pages=$_GET['p']; 
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(ip_id) FROM in_product"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query); 
        $rows = @mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM); 
        $records = $rows[0]; 

    if ($records > $pagerows) {
        $pages = ceil($records/$pagerows); 
    }else{ 
        $pages = 1; 
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric ($_GET['s'])) {
        $start = $_GET['s']; 
    }else{ 
        $start = 0; 
    } 


    echo "<table class='tableadmin2'> 
    <tr>
    <td class='td2'><b>Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;Cart: </b></td>
    <td class='td2'><b>Product Information: </b></td> 
    <td class='td2'><b>Product Photo: </b></td>
    <td class='td2'><b>Select Amount: </b></td>
    </tr>";

    $display6="SELECT * 
        FROM in_product LIMIT $start, $pagerows; " ; 
    $displayResult6 = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display6)
                or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

    while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult6, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $i = 1;
    $x = $row6['ip_stock'];
    $y = " ";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
    $y = "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";
     }            
    echo "<tr>
    <input type='hidden' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' /></td>
    <td class='td2'><a href='addcartInstate.php?ip_id=" . $row6['ip_id'] . "'>Add To Cart&nbsp</a></td>
    <td class='td2'><strong> " . $row6['ip_name'] . " </strong><br> " . $row6['ip_desc'] . " <br> $" . $row6['ip_price'] . " </td>
    <td class='td2'><img alt='first' src=" . $row6['ip_image'] . " width='300' height='250'></td>
     <td class='td2'><br>
         <b>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br>
                <select id='orderIn_quantity' name='orderIn_quantity'>
                    <option value='Select'> Select </option> 
                    $y                                              
                </select>
     </td>
    </tr>";
   }
    echo "</table>";

    if(isset($_POST['orderIn_quantity'])) {
        $orderIn_quantity = $_POST['orderIn_quantity'];
        } 

    if($pages > 1) { 
        echo '<p class="table3">'; 
        $current = ($start/$pagerows) + 1;
        if ($current != 1) { 
            echo '<a href="instate.php?s=' . ($start - $pagerows) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Previous Page </a>'; 
        }  
        if ($current != $pages) { 
            echo '<a href="instate.php?s=' . ($start + $pagerows) . '&p=' . $pages . '">Next Page </a> '; 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are there errors? Are you using error checking? Have you looked at the error logs?

Comment: Forgot to add this...This code grabs the value contained in the database, but only displays that value, does not forloop through that value to populate many selections based on that value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! One thing that we ask is that you pair your code down to the specific problem. Like @JayBlanchard said, show us what errors you have. Define "doesn't work" and show the pieces of the code that are relevant

Comment: I appreciate all the comments, I was missing one . and my problem is now solved and all is working. Sorry if I was too vague, but I do truly appreciate the fix. Thank you community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I can see it will display only the last value, correct? Because you keep overwriting your previous option with the new one. You need to use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

You need to change

```
$y = "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";
```

to

```
// this will append new string to previous string
$y .= "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! I can't believe I was so close. Missing one

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to $y not overwrite it. Also you should probably stick to eiter concatenation or variable interpretation when echoing strings, so when you output $y do it with concatenation:

```
$y='';
for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
    $y =. "<option value='" . $i . "'>". $i ."</option>";
 }            
echo "<tr>
<input type='hidden' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' /></td>
<td class='td2'><a href='addcartInstate.php?ip_id=" . $row6['ip_id'] . "'>Add To Cart&nbsp</a></td>
<td class='td2'><strong> " . $row6['ip_name'] . " </strong><br> " . $row6['ip_desc'] . " <br> $" . $row6['ip_price'] . " </td>
<td class='td2'><img alt='first' src=" . $row6['ip_image'] . " width='300' height='250'></td>
 <td class='td2'><br>
     <b>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br>
            <select id='orderIn_quantity' name='orderIn_quantity'>
                <option value='Select'> Select </option> 
                ". $y ."                                            
            </select>
 </td>
</tr>";
```